# Running a web application within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp

I have opened a JSP web project in Eclipse but not sure how to run the .jsp pages from the Eclipse. How can I add Tomcat to my Eclipse project and can run web pages directly from there?

Following tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

I found that by right clicking the project > Properties there is no option of Server there.

Comment: are you new to eclipse or all web app thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL+3 , then type 'Servers'. Select the desired tomcat server , then right click on it - choose Add, and in the dialog that opens choose the web application you like to run under this server.
When you're finish, simply right click on the server and choose run/debug

Comment: in New Server wizard there is no apache, just HTTP Preview, HTTP Server, J2EE Preview...

Comment: You probably have just the basic servers. do you have a small link over there that says: "Download additional server adapters?

Comment: Yes its basic. I just download J2EE version